# Линкует .lib вместо .dll

Tags: c++, cmake

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)

add_library(MessageLib
    SHARED
    lib/hello.hpp
    lib/hello.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld MessageLib)
```

При сборке проекта (cmake --build), линкер почему-то пытается подключить статическую библиотеку (.lib), но при этом cmake генерирует динамическую (.dll). То есть, если вместо SHARED указать STATIC, то проект будет успешно собран.

Ошибка при сборке с параметром SHARED:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "Debug\MessageLib.lib"
```

---

UPD:
На Linux все сработало, без проблем. На Windows проблема актуальна. Возможно необходимо просто указать флаг компилятору? На Win используется clang-cl, на Linux: gcc.

---

UPD2:
Сборка проекта https://github.com/punkochel/hello-project

Log сборки проекта CMake:

```
PS D:\Users\username\Desktop\hello-project\build> cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31631.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31631.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Users/username/Desktop/hello-project/build
PS D:\Users\username\Desktop\hello-project\build>
```

Log компоновки проекта:

```
PS D:\Users\username\Desktop\hello-project\build> cmake --build .
MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff for .NET Framework
  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule D:/Users/username/Desktop/hello-project/CMakeLists.txt
  hello.cpp
  MessageLib.vcxproj -> D:\Users\username\Desktop\hello-project\build\Debug\MessageLib.dll
  Building Custom Rule D:/Users/username/Desktop/hello-project/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "Debug\MessageLib.lib" [D:\Users\username\Desktop\hello-project\buil
d\HelloWorld.vcxproj]
PS D:\Users\username\Desktop\hello-project\build>
```

---

Решение проблемы отражено в комментариях к данному вопросу.

Comment: .lib может быть как статической библиотекой, так и библиотекой импорта. Линкер ms не использует .dll при сборке.

Comment: А как тогда использовать DLL в своем проекте? Я создал репозиторий проекта на GH: https://github.com/punkochel/hello-project

Comment: При сборке .dll  должен еще обязательно появляться соответствующий .lib файл

Comment: @user7860670, Если сначала через add_library собрать STATIC-файл (.lib), а затем создать SHARED-файл (.dll), и с помощью target_link_libraries прилинковать SHARED-файл, то будет та же самая ошибка. То есть использовать .lib я могу, а использовать .dll не могу, может для Win необходимо в DLL какой-то интерфейс организовать? Дело в том, что на Linux то все работает отлично. Я могу использовать либо .a либо .so и никаких проблем, а на Win постоянно какая-то дичь с этим со всем.

Comment: .lib должно создаваться при сборке SHARED библиотеки

Comment: @user7860670, так а не создается. Создается только .dll и .pdb. Как я могу попробовать с помощью CMake создать .dll, который можно будет подключить к .exe? Есть какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: *"а на Win постоянно какая-то дичь с этим со всем"* - вообще-то наоборот, это на Linux постоянно какая-то дичь с этим со всем: чтобы прилинковать динамическую библиотеку надо, чтобы она уже была собрана, так как библиотек импорта не предусмотрено, то в качестве альтернативы приходится использовать стабы, это и так ущербная альтернатива, но еще об их существовании мало кто знает, а те, кто знает, редко заморачиваются.

Comment: У меня создается и lib файл. Если у вас не создается, то указывайте, чем и как именно вы это все собираете, и полный лог сборки (чтобы были видны выполняемые команды).

Comment: @user7860670, добавил логи в основную тему.

Comment: А у вас экспортуруются функции? Нужно добавить либо файл экспорта, либо указать явно что функции экспортируемые: `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: Что-то не удается воспроизвести. Я получаю ошибку `NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'MessageLib.lib'` И это не удивительно, так как библиотека ничего не экспортирует.

Comment: Хотя нет, теперь удалось - лог, как в вопросе создается при попытке запуска cmake из cmd без настройки окружения. Поэтому там срабатывает `Building Custom Rule D:/Users/username/Desktop/hello-project/CMakeLists.txt`. А при запуске из native tools command prompt запускается nmake. Также смотрите https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-170

Comment: @ori, нет, но тут не в этом дело.

Comment: @user7860670, Спасибо что потратили время на решение моей проблемы. Видимо я еще пока не понимаю как это можно исправить. Да, я запускаю сборку cmake из PowerShell, но что конкретно изменить, чтобы у меня все собиралось, не понимаю.

Comment: Вам надо сделать, чтобы функция экспортировалась. Добавьте в заголовочном файлом перед ней `__declspec(dllimport)`, а в файле реализации `__declspec(dllexport)`. По-хорошему, что все надо делать при объявлении применяя условную компиляцию, но для этого примера сойдет и так.

Comment: @user7860670, Спасибо, это рабочий вариант. У меня сработало. Я нашел еще одно решение, это указать в CMakeLists переменную CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS со значением ON (set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)) перед add_library. Это тоже сработало у меня. Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: Вот `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` делать как раз не стоит, это же эмуляция поведения, которое есть на linux - с вываливанием вообще всех символов.

Comment: @user7860670, Да, я как раз читаю сейчас об этом. То есть вариант то рабочий... Теперь понятно почему у меня с .so в Ubuntu все четко работало. Только почему интересно в Linux данная фича стоит по дефолту и все приняли её как данное, а вот с виндой пытаются каждый случай вылавливать? Есть интересная функция с которой можно еще поиграться: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html. А так да, директивы условной компиляции никто не отменял, наверное это пожалуй единственный способ пока-что.

Comment: Потенциальных причин две: низкое качество разработки (открытость gnu/linux получил не из-за какой-то особой щедрости разработчиков, а потому что это всегда было такое гуано, что никому не было охота озадачиваться лицензионной защитой) или же может были какие-то ограничения лицензионного толка. *"и все приняли её как данное"* - скорее часть о наличии этой проблемы даже не догадываются, а другие уже понаступали на эти грабли и теперь для них это еще одна колдобойна из многих.

Comment: Чем дальше, тем интереснее) Спасибо за объяснение!